Unexpected dangling-reference warning with gcc 13, how to avoid it?
The following c++ code gives me a Wdangling-reference warning with gcc 13/14 when I compile with -Wall -Wextra.
# include <iostream>

std::string create_default_x() noexcept
{
    std::string default_x = "hello world";
    return default_x;
}

std::string const& get_x(std::string const& force_x = "") noexcept;

int main()
{
    std::string const& x = get_x();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

std::string const& get_x(std::string const& force_x) noexcept
{
    static std::string x = (force_x.empty() ? create_default_x() : std::string());
    if(!force_x.empty())
        x = force_x;
    return x;
}

See https://godbolt.org/z/498jnq3ee
I don't understand why. I realy think my code is ok. Is it possible to avoid it ? I don't see any option like "-Wno-dangling-reference" in the documentation.

Gcc seems to have issues like these. Here is an old post where also we seem to get a false positive. Is g++ -Wdangling-reference warning justified in this case? and also GCC 14 "possibly dangling reference to a temporary" warning or not, depending on the function argument.

"Is it possible to avoid it ? ..." As mentioned there you can use -Wno-dangling-reference or drop -Wextra

@user12002570 drop -Wextra is not a credible solution. Option -Wno-dangling-reference is then missing in the documentation ? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Here is the -Wno-dangling-reference mentioned.

BTW: static std::string x; return x; (ignoring the argument) is a smaller example. It looks like this happens because get_x could return its argument - which is a reference to a temporary - and the analysis doesn't look inside get_x.

The warning disappears if you define get_x before main, which suggests that the analysis does look inside it if the definition is known at the point of calling it.

@molbdnilo I saw that. But most of the time the definition in in the .cpp file.
